# Is there a python datastructure that would allow efficient range queries?

Tags: python, data-structures, window, range

Say, you had a list of integers, e.g.

```
foo = [3,9,23,54,77,123,...]
```

Is there an **efficient** datastructure that would allow queries like

```
x = everything in foo between 10 and 100
```

so that

```
x == [23,54,77]
```

or
    x = everything < 50

giving

```
x = [3,9,23]
```

etc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming these integers are already sorted it's not a data structure that you want, but an algorithm: that is, binary search. In Python this is provided by the [`bisect` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html).

So, for example, to find all the members that are less than 50:

```
from bisect import bisect_left
i = bisect_left(foo, 50)
result = foo[:i]
```

Answer (score 3):

There is the `range` function (or `xrange` in python 2):

```
foo = [3,9,23,54,77,123]

x = [y for y in foo if y in range(10,101)]
# x = [23,54,77]
```

If there's an infinite number on one side, use the operators and add `float(y).is_integer()` to match only integers:

```
x = [y for y in foo if y < 50 if float(y).is_integer()]
# x = [3,9,23]
```

Comment: I guess so, those are still O(n).  Was hoping for something more efficient